# Изменить размер логотипа wordpress темаTwenty Seventeen

Tags: css, wordpress

Как изменить размер логотипа wordpress тема Twenty Seventeen, с помощью дополнительного CSS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
.custom-logo-link img {
    max-height: 250px;
}
```